# Using optionally authorized routes with passport and express

Tags: express, jwt, authorization, passport.js

I would like to make some currently authenticated routes to be optionally authenticated. So that on my routes I could just simply add a public middleware to my router in a following manner:

```
.get('/projects/:id', public)
```

My current app.js flow looks like this:

```
// Authentication
app.use(authRoute);

app.use(defaultRouter);

// request handling
app.all('*', defaultRequestHandler);
```

So by default all my routes are authenticated, and in my authRoute I do a passport authentication, where I assign the user id to the request.

Using the previous flow, the only way I could think of to make it happen, was to assign an anonymous user id to the request in authRoute if the authentication fails. Also add another middle layer between authRoute and router, which checks from a list if the request url is a public route or not. Is there a simpler way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

me im doing it like this:

you have structure like following as example:

```
-controllers
-helpers
-public
-routes 
--index.js 
--api 
--- index.js 
--- subscriber.js
-views
```

in app.js:

```
app.use('/', './routes/index');
```

in directory routes in index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(middleware(),require('./api');
router.use(require('./auth');
module.exports = router;
```

in directory routes/api in index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/subscriber', require('./subscriber'));
module.exports = router;
```

So every Route which is in directory API is using the auth middleware.
When you add a new rout which needs to be controlled about authentication you can add a new rout in the index.js file in the directory './api/'
Every other route is defined in another folder.